# How to generate a single LLVM IR from multiple sources

Tags: c, gcc, clang, llvm, llvm-gcc

Compiling .c files to a single LLVM IR and link multiple libraries during the compilation.

An example here with gcc:

```
gcc -c -Wall -g3 -DVERSION=\"1.1.2\" ssl_proxy.c -o ssl_proxy.o
gcc -o ssl_proxy ssl_proxy.o  -lssl -lcrypto
```

Now, I want to compile the `ssl_proxy.c` to `ssl_proxy.ll`, simply using `llvm-gcc -S -emit-llvm` won't work as it will not let me link `-lssl -lcrypto` libraries.

Through this example I hope people can explain a bit more details about compilation with `llvm-gcc` (not clang), so that all visitors can learn from it and know how to compile complex multiple sources into one LLVM IR.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling source files into LLVM IR does not perform linking, so it does not require any libraries - it just needs the headers.

Comment: Then how should I perform the link with `-lssl -lcrypto` in this case for IR?

Comment: @cache the best approach is to let clang do the linking - give it your IR file as one of the inputs. You can also link directly with the gold linker if you install [LLVM's plugin for it](http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html), and that way you also enjoy some link-time optimization.

Comment: Thanks! But as I said if you could put more details and focusing on the example I provided. That may be the best way for ppl to learn.

Comment: @ Oak So could you please give detail commands to make the above into the IR and properly link those flags?